# obtain external jar's class's local variable in spring boot web project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a project A which contains a class KMeans.java. The class contains a public local varaible `iteration`. I build the project to a jar and add the jar to my spring boot web project B.

```
/**
ProjectA.jar
--KMeans.java
*/
public class KMeans{
  public int iteration;

  public void run(){
    for( iteration=0; iteration<1000; iteration++){
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

I try to obtain the `iteration` value in B to show it in web page dynamically. However, I dont know how to obtain the value. Thus, I decide to write the value into database.

I create a class `ModelStatusUtils.java` in A which contains `save(int iteration)` method.

```
  public abstract class ModelStatusUtils{
     public abstract void save(int iteration);
  }
```

And I put the class as a parameter in `run()` method in `KMeans.java` so that I can save the iteration which can be controlled by external class.

```
  ....
  public void run(ModelStatusUtils model){

     for( iteration=0; iteration<1000; iteration++){
      ....
      model.save(iteration);
     }
  }
  ...
```

Next, I create a class `WebModelStatusUtils.java` in B (I think the following error is because WebModelStatusUtils extends ModelStatusUtils in A, so spring boot cannot scan the package and could not autowired jpa correctly) that extends `ModelStatusUtils.java` . I used jpa and autowired the jpa in `WebModelStatusUtils.java`.

```
  public class WebModelStatusUtils extends ModelStatusUtils{
    @Autowired
    private ModelStatusRepository modelStatusRepository;

    @Override
    public int saveIteration(int i) {
      ModelStatus modelStatus = new ModelStatus(i);
      modelStatusRepository.save(modelStatus);
      return 1;
     }

  }
```

And repository is:

```
public interface ModelStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<ModelStatus, Long> {
}
```

However, it calls error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null, at WebModelStatusUtils .saveIteration(WebModelStatusUtils .java:23) ~[classes/:na]
```

My question is:

1) how to obtain instance's local variable of the external jar in web project

2) Why it throws null exception. How should i to solve it

Comment: `The class contains a public local variable iteration`. This is not a `local variable` but `instance variable`

Comment: no. this is a web application and the class is implements from a external class @mrkernelpanic

Comment: @DuFei prove that the reason for your NPE is not the one linked in the duplicate. Post the relevant code. The fact that it's a web app and that your class *is implements from a external class* (whatever that might mean) is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, it is a duplicated problem